# Directory Listing in Windows Kernel

Tags: windows, file, kernel, driver, system

I need to find out the filenames of the specific folder.

You want to read the contents by executing ZwCreateFile() with that filename.

To do this, try to get the filenames in the folder by doing ZwQueryDirectoryFile().

However, even if there are many files in the folder, only the FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION structure with file name '.' And size 2 in Buffer is returned.

The return value of ZwQueryDirectoryFile() was well done with STATUS_SUCCESS.

Below is the source code.

```
UNICODE_STRING DirectoryName;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
HANDLE DirectoryHandle;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION DirInformation;

RtlInitUnicodeString(&DirectoryName, L"\\SystemRoot");
InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttributes, &DirectoryName, 

OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, 0, 0);

    Status = ZwCreateFile(
&DirectoryHandle, 
FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | SYNCHRONIZE, 
&ObjectAttributes, 
&IoStatusBlock, 
0, 0, 
FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 
FILE_OPEN, 
FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT | FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE, 
0, 0);

if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
{
    DBG("ZwCreateFile() Success");
}
else
{
    DBG("ZwCreateFile() Fail %08x", Status);
    return;
}

DirInformation = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION) * 512);

Status = NtQueryDirectoryFile(
DirectoryHandle, 
0, 0, 0, 
&IoStatusBlock, 
DirInformation, 
sizeof(FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION) * 512, 
FileBothDirectoryInformation, 
TRUE, 0, 0);

if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
{
    DBG("NtQueryDirectoryFile() Success");
}
else
{
    DBG("NtQueryDirectoryFile() Fail %08x", Status);
    ZwClose(DirectoryHandle);
    return;
}

while (1)
{
    UNICODE_STRING EntryName;
    EntryName.MaximumLength = EntryName.Length = (USHORT)DirInformation->FileNameLength;
    EntryName.Buffer = &DirInformation->FileName[0];

    DBG("TEST : %wZ", &EntryName);

    if (DirInformation->NextEntryOffset == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        DirInformation = (PFILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)(((PUCHAR)DirInformation) + DirInformation->NextEntryOffset);
    }
}
```

Below is the result of WinDbg.

[image]

Obviously there are many files in "\SystemRoot"("\??\C:\Windows").

I do not know why this happens.

Please help me.

Comment: You're passing true for `ReturnSingleEntry`. Also, it's not meaningful to use a multiple of `sizeof(FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION)`. Entries are variable sized depending on the length of the filename. Batch entries in a 4 KB buffer like WinAPI `FindNextFile` does, and loop calling `NtQueryDirectoryFile` until it returns `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES`. Refer to the fastfat driver function [`FatQueryDirectory`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/dirctrl.c#L222) for a concrete example of how an actual file system handles this system call.

Comment: oh my.... I made a terrible mistake. Thank you for your reply.